# TextField ViewModifier not conforming to ViewModifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewmodifier

I have this code in one of my views:

```
struct TextFieldClearButton: ViewModifier {

    @Binding var text: String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        HStack {

            content

            if !text.isEmpty {
                Button(
                    action: { self.text = "" },
                    label: {
                        Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator))
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get two errors:

1. `Type 'TextFieldClearButton' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'`
2. `Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Content' conform to 'View'`

How can I get rid of these errors and make this modifier compile?

[image]

It looks like I can't use `ViewModifier` at all. Adding super simple case errors out too??:

[image]

Comment: It is compiled and works fine here (Xcode 13.2), probably you have some naming conflict with other code.

Comment: this is weird. I can't see any naming conflicts as of now. I am running on Xcode Version 13.3 (13E113).

Comment: Retested with Xcode 13.3.1 / iOS 15.4 - compiled & works fine. Which deployment target version do you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You likely have a `struct`/`class` in your project named `Content`

If you have Xcode's standard dark theme the "mint"/"greenish" means it is "Project" defined.

[image]

When you are using Apple's definition it is pinkish/purple like `ViewModifier`, `View`, and `String` in your screenshot.

[image]

Search for `struct Content`, `class Content`, `enum Content`, etc. In your project, You will find the duplicate and then just change the name of the duplicate.

It could also be a generic `<Content: SomeProtocol>` or `<Content>` or `typealias Content`

You can confirm the duplicate by being more specific

[image]

Comment: Or declare the `body` method like this: `func body(content: SwiftUI.Content) -> some View`

Comment: @robmayoff `Content` is usually a generic `<Content: View>` or a `typealias` it isn't a part of `SwiftUI` so `SwiftUI.Content` will not work. `ViewModifier.Content` will likely work but why compensate every time you need to use it (or others) when you can just rename the duplicate. It seems better for continuity too.

Comment: Oops yes I should have said `ViewModifier.Content`, not `SwiftUI.Content`.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI errors are really weird. In this case, the error is with the `Color` constructor. Change `Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator)`

to

`Color(uiColor: UIColor.opaqueSeparator)`

Comment: tried that, not working still.

Comment: Did you import UIKit?

Comment: yes, I did import UIKit