# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments when I implement Toggle switch in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to implement Toggle Switch as you see in the picture below, but I obtain the following error (the part on light red in the picture) using Xcode 14 and macOS 12.6.3:
[image]

I am refering also to the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toggle/init(_:sources:ison:)-39rkx

But it gives the same code. I would appreciate an idea on how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Please see [ask] -- the section on why to include code as text and not an image

Comment: Rename the struct `Toggle`. It clashes with the built-in type. And remove `Text(`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TextField ViewModifier not conforming to ViewModifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698728/textfield-viewmodifier-not-conforming-to-viewmodifier)