# How do I change my code from using NavigationView to NavigationStack?

Tags: swiftui, navigation

I'm new to swiftui and I need help transitioning my code from using NavigationView to NavigationStack. The reason I need to do this is to be able to let the user go back to the root view of the stack(which is my content view file). Also navigationview is deprecated in iOS 16 so I think its better I just learn how to use it now rather than later. I've attached a picture of my code with the current errors. Please let me know if I need to post any additional information that is needed to help me.

My current code with the errors:

[image]

I'm currently using navigation view which works but doesn't give the user the ability to go back to the root view. So I need to update my code to use NavigatinView instead but I'm not sure how to update my code to get rid of the errors that show when I change it to navigationstack.

Comment: Please post code as text directly in your question. Code in pictures can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698728/textfield-viewmodifier-not-conforming-to-viewmodifier/72363048#72363048

Comment: also check the official info at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upgrade to `NavigationStack` you need to use the new value-based `NavigationLink` and `.navigationDestination`, e.g.

```
List(exercises) { exercise in
    NavigationLink(exercise.title, value: exercise)
}
.navigationDestination(for: ExerciseView.self) { exercise in
    ExerciseView(exercise: exercise)
}
```

Note: you can have multiple `.navigationDestination` and they be positioned anywhere in the `View` hierarchy below the `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationLink initialiser that you want needs 2 params: destination and label.

```swift
NavigationLink {
    ExerciseView(...)
} label: {
    Text("Something")
}
```

Hope this helps!