# Placing Marker in MapKit using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, google-maps-markers

I am trying to adjust the extent of map in the Map() statement. This is for a golf app, and depending on the hole location I want to limit the map extent for that particular hole.  The current code covers the entire golf course but as soon as I add the coordinateRegion to Map(), I get an error message...I am at a loss on what I am doing wrong...

Here is the code that works.. however as soon as I change "Map()" to "Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion)", I get an error message "Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored"

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var current_hole: Int = 0
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion( center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 29.65,         longitude: -95.9333), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
    

    
    var userLatitude: String {
        return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"
    }
    var userLongitude: String {
        return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
    }
    
      
        var body: some View {

        Map(){ // error if changed to Map(coordinaterRegion: $mapRegion)
            
            Marker("", coordinate: wf_pin_coordinates[0])
            Marker("",  coordinate: wf_pin_coordinates[1])
            Marker("",  coordinate: wf_pin_coordinates[2])
            //... and so on
        }.mapStyle(.hybrid)
                
        HStack {
            Button(("Hole "+String(current_hole+1))) {
                current_hole = current_hole + 1
                if ( current_hole > 17 ) {
                    current_hole = 0
                }
            }
            Text(hole_description[current_hole]).fontWeight(.bold)
        }
            
        }
            
    }



#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: The default position of the most recent version of `Map` is based on a `MapCameraPosition`, the related init method is [`init(position:bounds:interactionModes:scope:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map/4231673-init)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698728/textfield-viewmodifier-not-conforming-to-viewmodifier/72363048#72363048

Comment: Thanks Vadian.. still not sure how I change to extent though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes in the most recent version of the `Map` struct.

Replace

```
@State var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion( center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 29.65,         longitude: -95.9333), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
```

with

```
@State private var cameraPosition = MapCameraPosition.region(
    MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 29.65, longitude: -95.9333),
                       span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03)))
```

and

```
Map() {
```

with

```
Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
```