"Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder' when using Image(song.image) in SwiftUI"
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct Song: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let artist: String
    let image: String
    let mp3FileName: String
}

struct MusicView: View {
    let songs: [Song] = [
        Song(title: "Warriors", artist: "Imagine Dragons", image: "warriors", mp3FileName: "Warriors (ft. Imagine Dragons)"),
        // other songs
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(songs) { song in
                    HStack {
                        Image(song.image) // Error here Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(song.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(song.artist)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What I tried:

I checked that the image names in the assets match exactly with the images in my asset catalog.

I confirmed that the images exist in the asset catalog.


Expected behavior:
I expect the images to be displayed next to the song titles and artists.
Error:
Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder' on Image(song.image)
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Did you mean Image(song.image,bundle:nil)?

Have you perhaps created another class called Image?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698728/textfield-viewmodifier-not-conforming-to-viewmodifier/72363048#72363048
